# Проблема при запуске PyQt6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6, windows-11

Ошибка:

> from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: 
> The specified procedure could not be found.

у меня винда 11, как решить эту проблему?

Вот код:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
window.show()  

app.exec()
```

Comment: Проверьте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77585434/python-pyqt6-dll-load-failed

Comment: ОГРОМЕННОЕ СПАСИБО ПОМОГЛО!

Comment: nurd 14 пожалуйста .

Comment: вопрос удалять не буду, админи хай закроют просто его

Comment: nurd 14 все правильно, закрывать не надо.

Comment: ок тогда пусть остаётся как есть